# Rails- sort users in alphabetical order of their names using solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, solr, sunspot

In my model `employee.rb` I have

```
  searchable do
    string :status
    integer :user_id
    string :profession do
      user.job_role
    end
    string :employee_name do
      user.first_name
    end
  end
```

In the index method of controller, I am doing the solr search as

```
  @search = Employee.solr_search do
    with :user_id, id
    with :status, params[:status] unless params[:status].blank?
    with :profession, params[:profession] unless params[:profession].blank?
    order_by :employee_name
    paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 50
  end
```

as you can see I am trying to sort Employees based on their first_name using

order_by `:employee_name`

but the results are not quite what I expect.
For example user with name `Tom Hanks` apper before usre `Fname1 Lname1`.

What is the best way to sort employees in Alphabetical order of their names?

Comment: Once solr gives the active record array? is there a performance problem if you sort it?

Comment: Is there a way I can sort it before solr gives active record array?

Comment: Have you changed the field type from text to string after indexing without clearing the index in between? The `string` field (in Solr terminology, I assume that Sunspot maps to that field type) is necessary (or a textfield with a keywordtokenizer) to get appropriate sorting - otherwise you'll see issues like you're mentioning (if indexed as a text-based field where tokenization takes place).

Comment: @MatsLindh great tip, I indeed changed field type from text to string. How to fix this problem?

Comment: @TonyVincent Delete everything from the Solr index and reindex your content. See [How can I delete all documents from my index](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#How_can_I_delete_all_documents_from_my_index.3F) for a quick way to do the first :-)

Answer (score 1):

Text fields are tokenized, which means that they're split into separate tokens based on some criteria (usually whitespace and special characters, but it depends on which tokenizer is set for the field). When Lucene then tries to sort this, it'll pick one of the *resulting tokens* and use that, ending up with an apparently random sort.

Instead, make sure to use a string field for a field used for sorting, so that there's only a single value present. The other option is to use a TextField with a KeywordTokenizer, as the KeywordTokenizer keeps the input text as a single token instead of splitting it up into multiple tokens - giving the same end result as using a string field. The difference is that a TextField with a KeywordTokenizer allows you to attach filters (be careful not to use filters that split text into multiple tokens again) such as a LowercaseFilter if you want sorting to be case insensitive.

If you've already indexed your content as as Text Field, you're going to have to reindex everything - [delete the content of the index](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#How_can_I_delete_all_documents_from_my_index.3F) and resubmit the documents to Solr for processing from the scratch again.